# How can i position a button in between two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to position a button in between two layouts.

Also, I don't want to have to do this with a margin if I can help it, when you start dealing with different screen sizes margin breaks down.
(In this image, I am trying to position the green button in between two layouts)

[image: Desired resulting layout]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/busy_white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_default_round"
            android:background="@drawable/ring_status_clock_in"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="John Doe"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manager"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/translucent_black_90"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Today Total"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="08:32"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Week Total"
                android:gravity="right"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="24:32"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp">

        </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/dashboard_clock_in_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to have your two layouts and button nested in a relative layout

Comment: Hey bro,
Did you manage to solve that problem?

Comment: I have not solved it yet! I did have some tell my to try Frame Layouts, but I have not got around to trying it yet. I am hopping to see support for it in Android L.

Answer (score 12):

This kind of UI calls for overlap of multiple layers.

So FrameLayout is the hero here.

To give a basic idea of what we wish to achieve, we can sketch the screen and decide placements
[image]

*FL* is the main container which will be a FrameLayout.

You need to make a button of fixed height. Let's say BL is of height *bl* dp.

Simply provide a MarginBottom of length *bl/2* dp to the LinearLayout *LL*.

Where *LL* is the container which would contain the profile image and the works.

The layout file will look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ConcernedPortionofScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Parent FrameLayout 'FL' -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- This is Layout 'LL'
                 This is where you will place your image & the nice bg
            -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:background="#b2ebf2" />

            <!-- BL = 50dp -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="#558b2f"
                android:text="@android:string/ok"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RestofScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The output will look like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot... With slight modifications it worked for my use case :)

Comment: Hey guys i am having problem using this that i used this code inside scrollbar now "rest of screen" getting problem in my last item object its not showing . is there any solution regarding that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using a `RelativeLayout` in which you will put your two layouts and your button.
But if you want to put the button on top of the two layouts you have to put it in your `RelativeLayout` last because of the z-order, and then use the XML attribute `android:centerInParent`.

So your layout would be something like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout ...
        android:id="@+id/myLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" > <!-- Or wherever you want to position this layout -->
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myLayout1" > <!-- Or wherever you want to position this layout -->
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button ...
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_centerInParent="true" only center it within the layout it does not let you center in between the layers.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't understand your question well.
You can try to put your `Button` below your first layout and then set a negative `android:layout_marginTop`.
And then position your second layout below your first layout.
(but again if you want your button to be on top of both you have to put it last in your `RelativeLayout`)
I'm not sure there is a way to do it without using margins. But you can set up different values for the margin in your `values-xxx` folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement this by using Coordinator layout.We have to specify multiple layouts one by one and the both layout must be LinearLayout . Now we have to use layout_anchor attribute inside Button

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="#CDDC39"
                    android:layout_weight="50"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:background="#C6FF00"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/LinearLayout1"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                app:elevation="7dp"
                android:text:"click Me"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```