# Touchable view across two layouts

Tags: android

I want to make a button which lays between two layouts. I make layout in layout. In inner layout I make a button and movi it outside the layout by setting negative margin. The button is not clickable outside the wrapping layout. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Paste the code.

Comment: I have use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921153/how-can-i-position-a-button-in-between-two-layouts instead of negative margin.